# unexpected return type from list comprehension

Tags: f#

I am teaching myself a bit of F# by doing a bit of simple matrix mathematics. I decided to write a set of simple functions for combining two matrices as I thought that this would be a good way of learning list comprehensions. However when I compile it my unit tests produce a type mismatch exception.

```
//return a column from the matrix as a list
let getColumn(matrix: list<list<double>>, column:int) =
    [for row in matrix do yield row.Item(column)]
//return a row from the matrix as a list
let getRow(matrix: list<list<double>>, column:int) =
    matrix.Item(column)
//find the minimum width of the matrices in order to avoid index out of range exceptions
let minWidth(matrix1: list<list<double>>,matrix2: list<list<double>>) = 
    let width1 = [for row in matrix1 do yield row.Length] |> List.min
    let width2 = [for row in matrix2 do yield row.Length] |> List.min
    if width1 > width2 then width2 else width1
//find the minimum height of the matrices in order to avoid index out of range exceptions
let minHeight(matrix1: list<list<double>>,matrix2: list<list<double>>) = 
    let height1 = matrix1.Length
    let height2 = matrix2.Length
    if height1 > height2 then height2 else height1
//combine the two matrices
let concat(matrix1: list<list<double>>,matrix2: list<list<double>>) =
    let width = minWidth(matrix1, matrix2)
    let height = minHeight(matrix1, matrix2)
    [for y in 0 .. height do yield [for x in 0 .. width do yield (List.fold2 (fun acc a b -> acc + (a*b)), getRow(matrix1, y), getColumn(matrix2, x))]]
```

I was expecting the function to return a list of lists of type

```
double list list
```

However what it actually returns looks more like some kind of lambda expression

```
((int -> int list -> int list -> int) * double list * double list) list list
```

Can somebody tell me what is being returned, and how to force it to be evaluated into the list of lists that I originally expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a short answer and a long answer to your question.

### The short answer

The short version is that F# functions (like `List.fold2`) take multiple parameters not with commas the way you think they do, but with spaces in between. I.e., you should NOT call `List.fold2` like this:

```
List.fold2 (function, list1, list2)
```

but rather like this:

```
List.fold2 function list1 list2
```

Now, if you just remove the commas in your `List.fold2` call, you'll see that the compiler complains about your `getRow(matrix1, y)` call, and tells you to put parentheses around them. (And the outer pair of parentheses around `List.fold2` isn't actually needed). So this:

```
(List.fold2 (fun acc a b -> acc + (a*b)), getRow(matrix1, y), getColumn(matrix2, x))
```

Needs to turn into this:

```
List.fold2 (fun acc a b -> acc + (a*b)) (getRow(matrix1, y)) (getColumn(matrix2, x))
```

### The long answer

The way F# functions take multiple parameters is actually very different from most other languages such as C#. In fact, all F# functions take exactly one parameter! "But wait," you're probably thinking right now, "you *just now* showed me the syntax for F# functions taking multiple parameters!" Yes, I did. What's going on under the hood is a combination of **currying** and **partial application**. I'd write a long explanation, but Scott Wlaschin has already written one, that's much better than I could have written, so I'll just point you to the https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/thinking-functionally.html series to help you understand what's going on here. (The sections on currying and partial application are the ones you want, but I'd recommend reading the series in order because the later parts build on concepts introduced in earlier parts).

And yes, this "long" answer appears shorter than the "short" answer, but if you go read that series (and then the rest of Scott Wlaschin's excellent site), you'll find that it's much longer than the short answer. :-)

If you have more questions, I'll be happy to try to explain.